# Is there a difference between the Visual Basic Strings.Trim(String) method and the .NET String.Trim method?

Tags: string, vb.net

Is there a difference between using the Visual Basic (VB.NET) Strings.Trim(String) method:

```
Dim myString As String = "    myString    "
myString = Trim(myString)
```

and the .NET String.Trim method:

```
Dim myString As String = "    myString    "
myString = myString.Trim()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the results of these two methods can be different. The first Strings.Trim(String) method -- `Trim(myString)` -- trims *only spaces* off the leading and trailing parts of the string, not tabs or other whitespace characters. The second String.Trim method -- `myString.Trim()` -- trims *all whitespace* (including tabs, carriage returns, linefeeds ... any character for which IsWhiteSpace(char) returns true) off the leading and trailing parts of the string.

Comment: That's not entirely accurate.  Strings.Trim() recognizes U+0020 (normal space) and U+3000 (double-width space, common in East Asian text).  As was done in previous VB versions.

Answer (score 1):

The differences can be gleaned from the documentation,

Trim - VisualBasic namespace

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.trim?view=net-5.0

Trim - System namespace

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-5.0